# Partial View Model Error (.net Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have this model in my view:

```
@model MGDanismanlik.Controllers.SettingsController.WorkCampClas
```

I call this partial view bottom of the view:

```
@Html.Partial("MonthlyResultPartial")
```

This is the model I use in `MonthlyResultPartial`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MGDanismanlik.Controllers.SettingsController.WorkCampaignResultClass>
```

But when I run it I got this error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MGDanismanlik.Controllers.SettingsController+WorkCampClas', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MGDanismanlik.Controllers.SettingsController+WorkCampaignResultClass]'.

What's the problem? I use different model in my partial view. How can I solve this?

Comment: Pass the model in as a parameter: @Html.Partial("MontlyResultPartial", model)

Comment: Your Partial View is expecting an object of type IEnumerable<WorkCampaignResultClass> but your View is passing in an object of type WorkCampaignResultClass. You'll need to adjust either your View or Partial View so that the types align.

Comment: @bschellekens why my view and my partial view gotta have same models? Arent they seperated views?

Comment: Your view and partial view do NOT have to use the same model, BUT if you do NOT explicitly pass a reference to the model for the partial, then it is implied that the partial uses the same model.  See the comment from @GHDevOps for the call signature that you want to use.

Comment: I tried it but the model returned null. I have this --> public PartialViewResult MonthlyResultPartial() {...} in my controller. I send model in this method to my partial view. I couldnt understand whats the problem.

Comment: Inside WorkCampClas add a IEumerable<WorkCampaignResultsClass> property and then pass in that property into your partial. The partial model must be a property in the parent model.

Comment: @GHDevOps I think I couldnt explain myself correctly. However I solved it using Html.Action("MontlyResultPartial", "Settings") with this instead Html.Partial. I didnt change my models or send a model in the method.